# No Video Output

Tags: display, graphics-card, motherboard

My friend called me telling me his computer we built a while back is not having video output. I remember when we first built it, it didn't have output either, but I forgot how we fixed it. Now, it's happening again. I've tested the monitor and ll the external cords, they all work. We've replaced the PSU, tried a different GPU, took out the RAM, booted without the RAM, took out the motherboard, put the motherboard back in with standoffs ( forgot them the first time, oops), and unplugged everything that could be unplugged and plugged it back in, but to no avail. All the other fans (CPU, case, GPU) are running so I think that means it's working, but I get no beeps from the little speaker on boot. If anybody has any ideas that would be great. From what it looks like it might be the motherboard, but I want a good evaluation before we go and buy things.

Here's the build:

- Intel Core i5-3350P 3.1GHz Quad-Core Processor
- MSI B75MA-E33 Micro ATX LGA1155 Motherboard
- G.Skill Ripjaws X Series 8GB (2 x 4GB) DDR3-1600 Memory
- A-Data Premier Pro SP600 64GB 2.5" Solid State Drive
- Toshiba 2TB 3.5" 7200RPM Internal Hard Drive
- MSI GeForce GTX 650 1GB Video Card
- Windows 7 Ultimate

Comment: the board has Xfire and does it have some sort of onboard grafics  without a grafics card? So did you A) go through the bios for possible options that could effect it somehow. B) Check using whatever onboard video it might have C) make sure that whatever in the bios exists to have onboard or external GPU be the first one that is used.  Maybey the cmos battery is low and some bios settings you had made is no longer set?

Comment: @Psycogeek I've already tried it on the on board port with and without multiple GPUs installed. I'm not sure what you mean by the bios, but I cant't see anything on the screen, so if I need that for the bios, then that might not be an option.

Comment: yes you would have to have that working there first, which might mean to default the bios (clear the cmos, or pull the battery) which will reset all the other bios stuff. but until you get a view into the bios (at least) you do not have a lot to lose.

Comment: How do I reset the bios? What does that do to the computer? What is this battery? It's a desktop not a laptop btw.

Comment: you look in the manuel for the cmos jumper (on the motherboard), and move it usually from pins 1-2 to pins 3-4 while the computer is off, then put it back where it was. It resets everything, usually settings like raid achi and ide switching is one of the biggest changes that can change bootability. It reset any ram timings, any overclocking, any legasy USB settings, all back to defaults which is concidered "safer". Hopefully it will also engage the onboard video, but further reading about how that onboard video works would be nessisary.

Comment: The battery is the coin sized battery on the motherboard that is a lithium coin cell, it keeps the clock going when there is zero power on the board, and also maintains the bios settings. These batteries last as low as 2 years and as much as 10 years. When the battery does not hold power all your bios settings go away, which depending on what you changed can cause issues, insomuch as not booting, but would rarely keep you from getting back into the bios to re-adjust things.

Comment: Will resetting the bios mean I have to re-install drivers and OS?

Comment: no, it could mean you have to set a few bios things to boot back into the same OS and drivers you have now, but it doesnt change your software, this is a hardware operation.

Answer (score 0):

Try to clear CMOS settings. Regardless whether you played with BIOS settings or not it may help. Here are the places at pictures below, from the [B76MA-E33 manual](http://www.msi.com/support/mb/B75MAE33.html#down-manual)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Where do you get his jumper? Could I just hold a screwdriver between the pins while it boots

Comment: Also I'm sorry about my lack of instruction manual. That was the one thing my friend neglected to include in his box of computer goodies.

Comment: Making shorting by screwdriver generally sounds.

Comment: So, do I keep it shorted while it boots?

Comment: No, don't do it! The Red Exclamation Mark warns not to do that.

Comment: As can be seen it says "You can clear the CMOS Ram by shorting this jumper while the system is off. Afterwards, open the jumper. Do not clear the CMOS RAM while the system is on because it will damage the mainboard."

Comment: Ok, so I shorted it and then stopped, booted and it was not fixed. Thanks anyways for trying to help.

Comment: Did not you forget to plug in additional CPU power connector from power source to mainboard? it is small 4-pin cable, it is JPWR2 at the picture above.

Comment: I did not forget

Comment: If you could get another compliant mainboard to run all your stuff on it it would be exclude the potential issue of MB before you go spending money. As you had it without standoffs at the first time it could really cause shorting and kill MB. Need to exclude it, MB is the first candidate from my perspective.

Comment: Would it be safe to swap parts with my computer, or could that mess it up?

Comment: Which parts do you want to swap?

Comment: Probably the motherboard or GPU

Comment: Of coure, that's what I'm talking about. Check for compliance before. Or post here.

Comment: Check for compliance?

Answer (score 0):

OK, Guys Listen up

First of all , no Stand-offs in the original Build..... Big No No and very serious issue

do you remember if you started the computer up without standoffs, Maybe you shorted the board

Now, that aide

YOU HAVE A GRAPHICS ISSUE

Why are you changing the PSU
Why are You removing the motherboard

and disconnecting and reconnecting every conceivable device possible

troubleshoot effectively

1. Define is your Graphics accelerator ONBOARD of Via GRAPHICS CARD

Dont Flash the Motherboard Memory, What For? that's not going to do anything accept cause potential additional issues

2. other things to try before you go spending money
   have you configured the Primary Graphics Device at startup in the CMOS Settings

First answer these 2 questions and the we will troubleshoot further

3. oh one other thing, Consider that the monitor you are using could be of a certain Max Resolution, but the Resolution that the graphics card is set at, could be much higher, and therefore it will appear as a Black Screen

I'm an Expert at this stuff
if you want i'll talk you through it

Just answer the first 2 Questions first, and stop pulling things apart, and Flashing BIOS's

speak soon

Sorry my bad, You obviously have a graphics card

MSI GeForce GTX 650 1GB Video Card
with 3 outputs
VGA, DVI and HDMI  and it's a PCI Express Card

Ok , make sure that you CMOS is set to Boot Graphics from PCI Express

then, understand that each card has a primary Port and secondary and a slave

the VGA port is primary Usually

what port are you plugged into ?

Comment: I Understand and respect your point of view, However these are the facts, Even though you tried 3 different monitors it DOES NOT rule out the resolution issue, You can only rule it out, if you know the Resolution capabilities of the monitors, You could have been trying to achieve let's say 1080 when all the monitors supported no more than 1024x768, You need to know what they support, so ,  NOw, even the PSU was rubbish, it still has nothing to do with video output, so it's irrelevant, and as a professional You can't rely on "Usually when something stuffs up i do this" that's poor troubleshootn

Comment: now, if you do reassemble the whole system, and let's say that just the graphics card was not correctly inserted into the expansion port, YES, you will fix the issue, but that's like saying, i pulled my whole car apart to change the tyre, You need to define the problem, if the PSU needed, replacing that's great, replace it. but after replacing it, Your graphics issue did not get fixed,   right, of course.

Comment: did you find out those things that i asked you to find out. about the CMOS settings, and are the monitors plugged into the primary port, also its a good idea to make sure that your card is pushed in to the expansion port correctly,  find out those answers first then we can go from, Just Trust me OK, i have years of experience at this, I'll show you how to narrow down the problem efficiently.  let me know, thanks mate

Comment: Everything is plugged into the primary ports. I've even tried it with removing the GPU and going to the on board video. I have it plugged into the primary VGA port. I'm not sure what you want with the CMOS, but I shorted it while it was off like Ruslan told me to and it did not help. As far as troubleshooting goes, I'm just using what I know. I know how to build, I'll use building (deconstruction etc) as my troubleshooting method. So, yes I'm not doing it efficiently, but I'm saying it's the only way I know how, and thank you for helping me.

Comment: Thats not a problem, don't take offense,if it's the only way that you know how, then that's your way of doing it, and once, it was my only way that i knew how, that's fine, but with experience from others we learn, so let's move forward from that OK. and get your problem fixed

Comment: of course shorting the CMOS didn't help, so remember not to do that again, Now, since your not sure what i want you to do with the CMOS, i'm guessing that it's Most likely that You don't have experience with CMOS Settings, and hence it's most likely that's where your problem is because, you don't know how to check it, so, it's likely you missed it.  i'll try to explain it and lets work through it together,

Comment: When Your Computer Starts up it goes through a POST (Pre O/S Selft Test) Usually you Press DEL to enter Setup, during this process to interrupt the Process, an you'll be taken to another Menu, it's usually blue, but can vary in colours,  Most people call this the BIOS (it's not the BIOS, However it does communicate with the BIOS) this is the CMOS Configuration Utility,  Now, Learn how to navigate from Menu to Menu, and Try to find something in there that relates to the Graphics, usually it says something like INITIAL DISPLAY or something similar and check those settings, because...

Comment: When Your computer Starts up, it goes off that Display Port initially, Now, here's a scenario, You have no graphics.. right,  so, if the Initial Display setting is set to VGA, but your plugging into a Graphics card, then there will be no display, even the card works, However if it's set to PCI-e for the card, but the card is faulty and you change it to VGA without knowing what it does, You will also have no display, where you should be replacing the card.

Comment: Try that step, further to this, are you able to get a Video card, anything will do, that is a PCI-e card, You MUST CONFIRM that the card works, and Try Replacing ONLY the the cards,  ONLY Change one thing at a time, if you try multiple things at a time and you get a result, you won't know what caused the result,  When you figure out and find the Settings in CMOS for Graphics, don't forget to press F10 to Save and Exit for the changes to take effect,, also find out What resolution your current Monitor supports, and What is the Highest Resolution that your card supports

Comment: Consider this, Nothing could be faulty , it could just be that, Let's say that your Graphics Card supports 1920x1080  Resolution, but your Monitor supports something a little less,   Well, that means that the monitor is NOT CAPABLE of outputting that resolution, in this case, You will see a Black Screen, and that's Normal, the fix is to Find a Monitor that will support a resolution greater than that of the card, and then set the setting lower, in some cases, the setting, when changed, last several seconds then reverts back, but.. that's not always the case, let me know how you went

Comment: Try all that, give me your results, Please be as specific as possible, remember i'm troubleshooting your system blind here, so be specific if you could,  thanks mate

Comment: Oh, one other thing, remember that IF YOU REMOVE THE GPU, after setting the CMOS Settings to go off PCI-e for the intial display, the CMOS Will change the settings because there is no GPU, then when you insert the GPU again, The CMOS May not revert it to PCI-e,  and you would need to check that again,  be aware of that

Comment: I just got done with a little experiment. I switched out GPUs from his computer and my computer (functioning). Both computers failed to produce video output, but I'm thinking that's because I didn't install drivers for the new cards. When I returned the GPUs back to normal, mine functioned normally, but his still did not work. If I installed the drivers for another card on the same machine, what  would happen? That's where I stopped the experiment, because I was unsure, but my friend actually won a new GPU the other day, (GTX Titan Black) so might it help to try and install it and its drivers?

Comment: did you Uninstall the Old Graphics Driver and applications completely before inserting the new GPU ? if you did, Device Manager should have a yellow question mark next to Graphics Device,   , also Ensure that the GPU is enabled in the CMOS utility As the first graphics boot display device.