# No video output, tried everything

Tags: video, motherboard, gpu

My friends computer we built suddenly stopped producing video output. It's been a while and I've tried everything. We replaced the PSU, tried 2 different sets of RAM, 2 different CPUs 3 different graphics card, no graphics card, 2 different motherboards resetting CMOS on both boards. I've tried 3 different (functioning) monitors with functioning cords. Before, on the initial build, we forgot standoffs, none of the other parts switched fixed it and the little speaker made no beeps. this lead me to believe the problem was the mother board. Upon buying a new motherboard and installing, it's apparent that wasn't the case. With the new motherboard, I've tried to put in the disk that came with, and then pressed enter a lot (although I pressed capslock and no light turned on leading me to believe that the keyboard/port doesn't work) in an attempt to get it to install possibly. The only thing I haven't tried is the storage, but could that affect it? If anybody knows what the problem is, and or have a solution, that would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the build:
Intel Core i5-3350P 3.1GHz Quad-Core
Gigabyte GA-H61M-S1 Micro ATX LGA1155 Motherboard
G.Skill Ripjaws X Series 8GB (2 x 4GB) DDR3-1600 Memory
Asus GeForce GTX Titan Black 6GB Video Card
Windows 7

The previous motherboard was this :
MSI B75MA-E33 Micro ATX LGA1155

Comment: If you have tried all that I would say at this point all you can do is grab a fully functioning machine and start swapping the new build  pieces in and out one at a time to find a fault.  Something like this leads me to suspect a double fault somewhere(s).

Comment: I've tried the video card and RAM in my computer. The RAM worked, but I had no video output with the video card. I don't think it could be the video card though because It didn't work on the on board one. I will try to put his CPU into mine and see if mine works. If its not that, then can I assume that the new motherboard doesn't work?

Comment: RAM is an unlikely culprit for video problems.  If the video card did not work in your fully operational machine it is likely bad (did you make sure your drivers were uninstalled and the drivers for the other card were installed?).  If the on-board video does not work the mobo too could be bad.

Comment: I did not install any other drivers on my machine when using the new card. Recently however I tried his CPU in my machine, and it worked, so it's not the CPU, however I also tried putting my PSU into his machine (the one that is in it is new, but not great) and the speaker beeped nonstop. I checked the beep codes and it said this signifies a problem with the GPU, RAM, or motherboard. I've already tested the RAM and I took the GPU out which leads me to believe that both the motherboard and PSU (both brand new) are not fully functional. When I plugged his PSU back in, it didn't beep at all.

Comment: possible duplicate of [No Video Output](http://superuser.com/questions/771027/no-video-output)

Answer (score 2):

Last time I tried something like that, I had one of the screw/bolt things behind the motherboard place wrong and that caused a short circuit. To eliminate that possibility I recommend that you take the motherboard out of the casing. Test it on a table and start slow:

1. Make the motherboard beep.
   This is "proof of life" Connect only 3 parts: PSU, CPU and motherboard. That should make it beep, three short beeps to be exact. If it does not beep, then 1 of the 3 parts is defect.
2. Install RAM.
   If the motherboard have onboard video, then it should give a video out there at this stage, if it does not then it will beep, three long beeps.
3. Install graphics card.

I hope following those steps will get your building project back on track.

Comment: Nothing. No beeps. I might add that the computer was working prior to this problem, then failed to produce video output. I tested my CPU inside of his computer, with no results, however I did not try the opposite. I will also try switching PSUs. It is possible that my brand new motherboard was DOA.