# Constant beeping with new PSU, no video output

Tags: memory, graphics-card, cpu, motherboard, power-supply

So, my friends computer is not producing video output. The monitor works, I've tried the CPU and RAM inside of my computer, so I know they work. On the initial build we forgot standoffs and the motherboard produces no beep codes of any kind. This lead me to believe that it was t he motherboard.

Bought a new motherboard, still doesn't work.

I put my PSU into his machine, and get constant beeping from the motherboard. I look up the code, and it says its either RAM, GPU or motherboard. RAMs good, no GPU, so it's probably motherboard right? I did not put his PSU into my machine because I do not want to mess it up.

However when I switched back to his (brand new) PSU, the motherboard does not beep at all, leading me to believe that its the PSU. I am unsure whether its just the PSU, the PSU and the new motherboard, the PSU and the new motherboard, the PSU and both motherboards, or both motherboards that are not functional.

My friend declined to give me the manual for the original motherboard, so I cannot test it with my PSU. Anyone have any ideas on what the problem is, or how to fix it that would be great. If anyone knows of a different or better forum for this sort of thing, that would be nice too, because this is the 3rd ask I've made about this problem here, and I have found little help. Thank you.

Here's the original build:

-Intel Core i5-3350P 3.1GHz Quad-Core

-MSI B75MA-E33 Micro ATX LGA1155

-G.Skill Ripjaws X Series 8GB (2 x 4GB) DDR3-1600

-A-Data Premier Pro SP600 64GB 2.5" SSD

New motherboard:

Gigabyte GA-H61M-S1 Micro ATX LGA1155 Motherboard

The PSU (new) is not very powerful or good to begin with, and I have been unable to find any useful info on the part itself. (maker, wattage) I would look at the box, if I had it, but my friend (same one who didnt give me the MB manual) may have thrown it away and is also in NY at the moment (I'm in CA) I'm sorry about his lack of info.

Comment: some advice on SO postings: cut your text up so that no paragraph is taller than an inch. use complete sentences, but resist the urge to give us a blow-by-blow chronological story, but instead summarize whats wrong, the steps you have taken, and what your optimal result would be. Try to avoid extraneous detail, but model numbers would be most helpful in determining the compability of parts. Last, remember stack overflow is about archiving questions and answers, and is less about fixing a specific persons problem. other forums are more focused on specific support and you may have better luck.

Comment: possible duplicate of [No video output, tried everything](http://superuser.com/questions/776700/no-video-output-tried-everything)

Comment: reposting.... asking the same question multiple times

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/771027/no-video-output

Comment: Non stand offs indicates you shorted the motherboard we don't appreciate when people post the same question mutiple times

Comment: Well, when I get new info on the issue, or my previous question sinks into oblivion, how is it supposed to get answered then?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I could understand you check all parts, such as CPU, PSU, MB. So if the parts are believed to be OK themselves there could be a few issues with having all the parts connected properly and of compliance between parts. Remember that:

- CPU requires additional Power connector to be plugged in MB.
- CPU should be compliant with a particular MB.
- RAM sticks should be put in right DIMMs numbers/pairs and should have recommended clock rate (according a manual).
- Some CPU have no Graphical Unit, if it's your case, you need video card, because in-built video on MB won't work.

Mother board manual can be always download and the model can be found and read at the board itself.

You always have much more chances to get a result including names, makes, models of your MB,CPU and other parts.